# Semantic Versioning between Bamboo and Artifactory?

Tags: java, publish, artifactory, bamboo, semantic-versioning

We have an in-house Java lib that is a dependency for many other projects, let's call it `our-commons-<version>.jar`. We like the idea of following [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) more or less, so:

- Major number changes when we make backwards-incompatible API changes;
- Minor number changes when we make backwards-**compatible** API changes;
- Patch number changes every time we do a build (so for us, it's really a **build number**); but we really will only build when fixing a bug so its close enough to true `semver`

Currently, we only publish to a SNAPSHOT directory on Artifactory, and overwrite the JAR that's there every time we build. Specifically, we have our project repo at:

```
http://arty/artifactory/simple/our-libs-snapshots/our-commons/snapshot
```

Where `http://arty/artifactory` is the Artifactory service running on the `arty` machine, where `our-libs-snapshots` is the name of the actual repo, and where `our-commons` is the name of our lib. The `/snapshot` dir is where all Bamboo builds publish to, like I said, overwriting the JAR each build. We are hardcoding our build to produce an `our-commons-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` each build.

To do this publishing, I have the following task configured as part of our Bamboo plan for `our-commons`:

```
Artifactory Deploy Task
=======================
Artifactory Serverl URL:        http://arty/artifactory
Target Repository:              our-libs-snapshots
Deployer Username:              myadmin
Deployer Password:              ******
Edit Published Artifacts:       dist/our-commons-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar=>our-commons/snapshot
Capture & Publish Build Info:   yes (checked)
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get Bamboo and Artifactory working with our flavor of semver. Such that the first time we build, it will produce:

```
http://arty/artifactory/simple/our-libs-snapshots/our-commons/1.0.0/our-commons-1.0.0.jar
```

And the second time we build, it will produce:

```
http://arty/artifactory/simple/our-libs-snapshots/our-commons/1.0.1/our-commons-1.0.1.jar
```

Etc. Then, we would be able to manually indicate when we want to increase the minor number, in which case the patch number would start over again:

```
http://arty/artifactory/simple/our-libs-snapshots/our-commons/1.1.0/our-commons-1.1.0.jar
```

Same deal for major number, but incrementing that would reset *both* the minor and patch numbers.

Not sure where we should be adding this configurations should be added, or what they would actually look like. Any ideas?

Comment: Just for fun, are you coming from node.js/ruby background? :)

Comment: Thanks @JBaruch (+1) - nope, Java background. Why?!?

Comment: Abusing semantic versioning to achieve snapshot behavior is a natural thing to do for developers coming from those bgs.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to achieve is called *unique snapshots* (see below). Using `patch` versions of [semver](http://semver.org/) for that is wrong (Patch version is the third number, e.g. in `10.0.3` 3 is the patch version).

When working with Maven (or Gradle, or Ivy) and Artifactory, you have this feature out of the box.
You need to set Artifactory repository to work with [unique snapshots in repository settings](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Common+Settings#CommonSettings-MaxUniqueSnapshots) and [setup snapshots cleaning](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Common+Settings#CommonSettings-MaxUniqueSnapshots) (usually keeping 3 to 5 last snapshots is a good practice).

Comment: Thanks @JBaruch (+1) - can you provide some more details? Not sure what "patch versions" are, what "unique snapshots" are, and how they relate to each other. How do I configure Artifactory for "unique snapshots"? How do I "clean" snapshots? Thanks again!

Comment: Only if you promise to accept the answer (something that you don't do, for some reason). Just kidding. I'll update the answer in a few hours with additional details and links.

Comment: Clarification links added.